# ReferenceError: exports is not defined in ES module scope after built typescript and node module app

Tags: node.js, typescript, firebase, node-modules

I went through a number of answers on different platforms like this one but none of them helps to my issue.
I am creating a NodeJS app using Typescript and planning to deploy it to Firebase functions. I also use modules, import/export modules, and async functions. In both the development and built stages get an error:

```
file:///mnt/f/Worskpace/OsloCityBikes/firebase_server/functions/build/src/index.js:101
exports.app = functions.https.onRequest(app);
^

    ReferenceError: exports is not defined in ES module scope
    This file is being treated as an ES module because it has a '.js' file extension and '/mnt/f/Worskpace/OsloCityBikes/firebase_server/functions/package.json' contains "type": "module". To treat it as a CommonJS script, rename it to use the '.cjs' file extension.
        at file:///mnt/f/Worskpace/OsloCityBikes/firebase_server/functions/build/src/index.js:101:1
```

and during development (npm run dev):

```
[nodemon] starting `ts-node ./src/index.ts`
ReferenceError: exports is not defined in ES module scope
    at file:///mnt/f/Worskpace/OsloCityBikes/firebase_server/functions/src/index.ts:176:1
```

package.json

```
{
  "name": "functions",
  "scripts": {
    "lint": "eslint --ext .js,.ts --fix --ignore-pattern \"node_modules/\"",
    "build": "tsc && nodemon ./build/src/index.js",
    "build:watch": "tsc --watch",
    "serve": "npm run build && firebase emulators:start --only functions",
    "shell": "npm run build && firebase functions:shell",
    "start": "npm run shell",
    "deploy": "firebase deploy --only functions",
    "logs": "firebase functions:log",
    "dev": "nodemon ./src/index.ts"
  },
  "engines": {
    "node": "16"
  },
  "type": "module",
  "main": "build/src/index.js",
  "dependencies": {
    "axios": "^1.5.1",
    "cors": "^2.8.5",
    "express": "4.18.2",
    "firebase-admin": "^11.8.0",
    "firebase-functions": "^4.3.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/cors": "2.8.15",
    "@types/express": "4.17.20",
    "@types/node": "^20.8.7",
    "firebase-functions-test": "^3.1.0",
    "nodemon": "^3.0.1",
    "ts-node": "10.9.1",
    "typescript": "4.9.5"
  },
  "private": true
}
```

tsconfig.json

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es2020",                          
    "module": "NodeNext",                    
    "lib": ["es6", "ES2020", "ESNext"],                     
    "allowJs": true,
    "checkJs": true,
    "outDir": "./build",                          
    "rootDir": "./",
    "strict": true,         
    "noImplicitAny": true,
    "incremental": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "moduleResolution": "NodeNext",
    "isolatedModules": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true,
  },
  "compileOnSave": true,
  "include": [
    ".eslintrc.cjs",
    "src/"
  ],
  "ts-node": {
    "esm":true,
  }
}
```

index.ts

```
import functions from 'firebase-functions';
import express from 'express';
import { APIConnector } from './connectors/axiosConnector'; 
import { requestLogger, unknownEndpoint } from './utils/middleware';
import cors from 'cors';
const app = express();
app.use(cors());
app.use(requestLogger);
app.use(express.json());
const dataFetching = async () => {
    const fetchedData = { stationInformation: null, stationInformationState: null, stationStatus: null, stationStatusState: null };
    APIConnector.getJson('https://api.com/station_information.json', null)
        .then((data) => {
        fetchedData.stationInformation = stations;
        fetchedData.stationInformationState = {
            last_updated: data.last_updated,
            ttl: data.data.ttl,
            version: data.data.version,
        };
    });
};
const fetchedAPIData = await dataFetching();
app.get('/api/station_information', (request, response) => {
    response.json(fetchedAPIData.stationInformation);
});
app.use(unknownEndpoint);
const PORT = 3001;
app.listen(PORT, () => {
    console.log(`Server running on port ${PORT}`);
});
exports.app = functions.https.onRequest(app);
```

All my created modules and imported to index.ts are TS files and use

```
export function () {...}
```